# Encrypt decrypt methods for routerlink params in Angular

Tags: angular, encryption

I need proper way to encrypt and decrypt querystring params like **gmail.com**

and how to get these queryparam

*path is this*
`{ path: 'myPrograms/:sosid/:xy', component: MyProgramesComponent}`,

*and router link is this*

```
[routerLink]="['/myPrograms/',2,3]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your constructor:

`private activatedroute: ActivatedRoute`

You can access your `params` in this way on your `onInit` function:

```
 const sosid = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['sosid'];
 const xy = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['xy'];
```

**Note: your url should be something like localhost:4200/myPrograms/123/32**

then your `sosid` will have the value `123` and `xy` will have the value `32`.

The way you want to encrypt and decrypt is up to you. Theare infinite ways to do that. It just depends by you. For example you can decide to shift every ASCII key by one when encoding, and then shitf them back when decoding.

For example, if you decide that shift and the url is `.../myPrograms/452/56`, then the real data will be :

```
sosid : 341
xy : 45
```

This is just `ONE` way, even if it's so easy, to achieve what you want. So I don't think that SO can really help with that crypt/decrypt.

Comment: And you do a great job of helping users!